# Running class and bst file through command line/shell script

Tags: bibtex, compiling, windows

I am trying to run the latex project: http://www.sigchi.org/publications/chipubform/sigchi-papers-latex-template/at_download/file through command line. I have written a shell script(*.sh file), where I plan to execute *.tex with pdflatex, and *.bib with bibtex respectively. What and how shall I execute *.cls and *.bst files? So that it finally converts into the pdf!

So far I am done with:

```
pdflatex sigchi-sample.tex 
bibtex sample.bib
```

I however, don't know what to do with:

```
sigchi.cls
acm-sigchi.bst
```

The figure stays as it is in the folder, I guess. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with those two files: they are automatically loaded and used during the `pdflatex` and `bibtex` runs respectively.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your suggestion. So, I tried running the script. It ran this time (I don't know why it didn't run before), and it generated the *.pdf. However, it could not include the bib content in the References. The error I got it says: Output written on sigchi-sample.pdf (3 pages, 532776 bytes).
Transcript written on sigchi-sample.log.
I couldn't open file name `sample.bib.aux'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the second instruction is wrong: it should be `bibtex sample` (without `.bib`).

Comment: Thanks for your quick help @egreg but now it gives the error, saying "I couldn't open file name 'sample.aux'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct order of the commands should be

```
pdflatex sigchi-sample
bibtex sigchi-sample
```

You can omit the extension `.tex` and the input for `bibtex` must *definitely* not have the `.bib` extension (the implicit one is actually `.aux`).

The file names should be the same: `bibtex` reads the data produced by the first run of `pdflatex` and stored in `sigchi-sample.aux`.

Then you have to run again

```
pdflatex sigchi-sample
pdflatex sigchi-sample
```

in order that the bibliographic references are correctly solved. Of course it's not necessary to always do all four runs. Do them when you need to have the document in final form.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much @egreg! really appreciate your help!